# NGINX errors logs for WordPress site say that index.mjs.map file is missing

Tags: wordpress, maps, wordpress-theming

I'm having trouble getting my theme (Citadela) to load the google maps it claims it will display. I've checked all of my logs and this is the only error I can find.

`2023/12/05 09:56:40 [error] 2506475#2506475: *3307812 open() "/home/root-folder/htdocs/domain.ca/wp-includes/js/dist/index.mjs.map" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: CLIENT_IP_ADDRESS, server: terry.respectmap.ca, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/dist/index.mjs.map HTTP/2.0", host: "domain.ca"`

I'm guessing this means we're not running the scripts necessary to load maps client side. Does anyone have any insight on this error? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Tried disabling other plugins, reinstalling the theme, and reading all the error logs.

Comment: This `.map` file has nothing to do with geographic maps. It's generated for debugging purposes when creating a minified Javascript file, and the browser tries to retrieve it and fails.